# VB.Net no idea how to get this to compile also Retro BASIC

Tags: vb.net, basic

Hey I cant get this to compile, I guess VB.net is the best thing to try and get this code running in.

I am having most of my trouble with the Dim Called butter. "Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning BC42104 Variable 'butter' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.
"

System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "This " to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim cocco
        Dim apple
        Dim butter
        Dim rice

01:     GoTo 50
02:     cocco = apple + butter
04:     Print(cocco)
05:     Randomize(Timer)
06:     rice = 1
08:     rice = rice + Int(Rnd() * 10)
10: REM 
12:     GoTo 860
14:     apple = "random "
16:     butter = "number "
18:     cocco = apple + butter
20:     Print(cocco)
22:     GoTo 27
24: REM
26: REM
27:     Print(rice)
28:     GoTo 212
30: REM
50:     apple = "This "
60:     GoTo 02
210: REM
212:    apple = "and terminates "
214:    butter = ":-) !"
216:    cocco = apple + butter
218:    Print(cocco)
220:    End
850: REM
860:    apple = "only "
870:    butter = "prints "
880:    cocco = apple + butter
890:    Print(cocco)
900:    GoTo 14


    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: You're trying to compile BASIC using VB.NET? Also, the error is correct in your code - you're attempting to access `butter` before you've given it a value.

Comment: I think so, I really have no idea how you use either of them. I don't think windows has a basic compiler.

Comment: Just googling "basic compiler for windows 10" returns many results. Also, I think you need to learn about BASIC and VB.NET before you jump into the coding.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. A Windows form VB.net application that compiles. Check the Debug menu > Windows > Immediate That is where Debug.Print outputs to.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim cocco As String = ""
        Dim apple As String = "This "
        Dim butter As String = ""
        Dim rice As Integer
        cocco = apple & butter
        Debug.Print(cocco)
        Dim r As New Random
        rice = 1
        rice = rice + r.Next(10)
        apple = "only "
        butter = "prints "
        cocco = apple & butter
        Debug.Print(cocco)
        apple = "random "
        butter = "number "
        cocco = apple & butter
        Debug.Print(cocco)
        Debug.Print(rice)
        apple = "and terminates "
        butter = ":-) !"
        cocco = apple & butter
        Debug.Print(cocco)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with this code.  A few suggestions:
1) Click on "My Project" in the Solution Explorer.  Click the "Compile" link and set Option Strict on.  This will highlight many errors that you can then track down and fix.

2) All of your Dim statements should have a variable type associated with them.  For example, **dim butter as String = ""** and **dim rice as integer = 0**

3) While I think Goto statements do have some very specific uses, they contribute to spaghetti code.  Consider re-designing using sub routines instead.

Good luck and keep trying.

Comment: Hey cheers for the pointers, I use c# most of the time and I am pretty dreadful at that too, my mother keeps on sending me these god awful programming puzzles in the worst possible languages.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs in the Print statement.  In VB.Net Print defaults to Filesystem.Print - which expects an integer as the parameter.  If you change Print to Console.WriteLine then the output will appear in the Output window.

There's also a problem with Randomize(Timer) - as Timer is a class System.Windows.Forms, you can use Randomize() to initialize the random-number generator.

Comment: Hey cheers I don't really use console applications, so I just went with the copypasta, I guess I'll need a readline or somesort of break/pause at the end.

Comment: Yes Console.Read() something like that